Good reference for modules over graded-commutative rings
I have been doing some work recently on modules over graded-commutative rings (in particular, local in the graded sense and with $R_i=0$ for $i<0$). Many results in the ungraded context can easily be translated into the graded context, but is there some book, set of online notes, papers etc. that covers the fundamentals?
Most importantly, I would like to be able to save some time by being able to see what does and what doesn't translate nicely from the theory of modules over a commutative unital ring to the graded context.

I would recommend you to consider the following list:

Read the paragraph 1.5 named "Graded rings" and probably paragraph 1.8 named "Hilbert functions and polynomials" in David Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry
Work through the exercises 2.14-2.18 named "$\mathbb{Z}$-graded rings and their localisations" in the same book
Look at the paragraphs 4.5.4-4.5.6 named "Preliminaries on graded rings" in Ravi Vakil's The Rising Sea: Foundations of Algebraic Geometry and, if you are interested, go a little bit further to study how graded rings are related to geometry
If it is not enough, you can pay your attention at tag 00JL on The Stacks Project

Of course, there is much more algebra and geometry related to the notion of graded rings, but I think, this should be enough for the moment.
